# Is there a rule governing a switch from present perfect to simpler tenses?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-continuous

> — Where have you been?
>
> — I've been at a cafe. I was having lunch there.

I wonder when one should switch from the present perfect to simpler tenses. Is it a correct example (i.e. shouldn't it be "I have been having lunch there"? Is there a rule of thumb at least?

Comment: Why do you think there's any particular reason to use continuous verb forms here? Or indeed *any* unnecessarily complex tenses? There's no reason why the reply shouldn't have been ***I was at the cafe. I had lunch there*** - that's much simpler, and it's probably what most native speakers would say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I inferred that if the question is in the present perfect (Where have you been?"), the answer should also be in this tense (I've been...). I vaguely remember that tenses become simpler as the dialogue progresses, but I don't know how it works exactly.

As to your question, there's only one reason: the influence of my native language.

Comment: I haven't heard of the idea that "tenses become simpler as the dialogue progresses", but it certainly sounds convincing to me! I think idiomatically it's quite possible we're more likely to ask *Where have you been?* rather than *Where were you?*, if only because the Perfect version implies a stronger connection between Past and Present (and the speaker is ***currently*** interested in some *[recent] **past*** activity). But that's a very fine point, hardly worth even *noticing*, let alone "learning".

Answer (score 3):

The choice of the various aspectual constructions in English (perfect, continuous, "future", and their combinations) is rarely rule-governed. It mostly corresponds neither to any rule, nor to any objective difference, but purely to how the speaker is choosing to present the temporal focus and relationships.

When you use a perfect contruction you are choosing to set a temporal focus at some later time and look back on the events. When you use a continuous construction, you are choosing to present an event as a continuing state or activity. Sometimes there are implications that flow from that choice, but often there is no objective difference.

In your example, you could use a perfect for neither, the first, or both: the only combination that sounds odd is a simple past followed by a perfect. My hunch is that this is because the perfect is the marked form (specifies a temporal focus where the simple past doesn't) and it's odd to do that but not at the first opportunity.

Similarly, you can equally well use a continuous or not for the second senttence.

Comment: I like OP's suggestion that "tenses become simpler as the dialogue progresses". Is that a concept you're ever come across before? I do have a gut feel that Past Perfect is often only used once or twice before switching to Simple Past in any extended narrative context.

Comment: I agree with this. And I'll add: Often, a conversation will move from the present perfect to simple past when the time of an event is required: Where have you been? I've been at the café. Oh?, When **were you** there? I **was** there at noon.//My car **has broken** down. Really? Where **did it break down**? Though there are cases of: I've been at home all afternoon. I did not go to the shops today.

Comment: @Lambie I guess the words "when" and "where" somehow suggest that we're speaking of an expired period of time, so they require the past simple. (Where did you buy this hat? When did you see them?), we expect some narrative to follow. But I'm a little bit confused. What is the proper answer to the question "Where have you been?" is it "I've been to the cafe. I had lunch" or "I was at the cafe. I had lunch"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's true (about Past Perfect). He crashed as he had gone to sleep while he was driving (or had been driving - it's more complex)

Comment: @Rusletov When and where do not require any tense. What Colin says is basically true. I will illustrate in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possible dialogue using:
"Where have you been?" is it "I've been to the cafe. I had lunch" or "I was at the cafe. I had lunch"? – [That was the question in a comment from the OP.]

Q: Where **have you been?**
A: **I've been out**. With friends. What's it to you?
Q: I was just wondering....no need to be grumpy.

Q: Where **have you been**?
A: **I was out.**
Q: Out where? At a café or pub?
A: Yes, I was at a café where I had lunch.

Q: Where have you been?
A: I've been out.
Q: Oh, I see.
A: And I've already **had my** lunch.
Q: You have? At what time?
A: I **had lunch at 3:00.**

Q: Where have you been?
A: I've been out.
Q: Did you have lunch while you were out? Because I've made some lunch for us.
A: Yeah, I **had lunch with my mates at the pub.**

Q: Where the hell **have you been** all afternoon?
A: **I've been** home. I **did not go out** or even outside the entire time!

These are some of the possibilities. Often, a conversation will move from PP to SP if the situation requires referring to a specific event that is OVER.

The only rule is that if you want to express the idea that an event or situation is over, finished, you use the simple past. But it is really up to you. If, however, you refer to an event that is clearly finished using the Present Perfect that will be a red-flag in terms of fluency.....

Comment: I find those dialogue examples really supreme way to illustrate your explanation. However, you say that if the situation is over, I should use PS. But the following dialogue comes to mind: "Q: Where have you been? Why are you sweaty? A: I've been running" I reckon it's correct, but according to my understanding of your explanation, it should be "I ran" as the running is clearly finished.

Comment: @Rusletov No, my friend. There is no correct answer to that: BOTH are FINE. If the speaker **wants to signal the past without being specific**: I've been running by the river. But he might want to **be** specific, in which case he would say: Oh yeah, I ran all the way from Lenin's Mausoleum to the Tretyakov Gallery.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I can't quite grasp why you chose "I was out" rather than "I've been out" in your examples. There must be a reason.

Comment: @Rusletov I didn't.  I said, BOTH I'VE BEEN out and I WAS OUT. :) The answer to "Where have you been?" can BE EITHER ONE, depending on what the speaker wants to say or is thinking. Just repeat all my examples over and over. You will eventually "get" the difference....

Comment: Okay... but just to make sure, does it have anything to do with AmE often ignoring Present Perfect? As in "I already ate" instead of "I've already eaten", "I just came" instead of "I've just come". Can I say that the British would more likely say "I've been out" and the Americans would say "I was out".

Comment: @Rusletov I'm going to come over there and strangle you (JOKE). Forget that already thing. Not every British person goes around correctly trotting out  using the PP correctly. It's just that **in the MEDIA and in MOVIES**, you hear all this AmE speech, so it gives the impression that "all Americans" misuse the PP. This is entirely a class and education thing. And there are a lot of uneducated Americans sounding off in the media. Somehow, this myth has been perpetrated (on SE also) that Americans don't use the PP. What rubbish, it really annoys the hell out of me.

Comment: I can still hear my mother's (college educated) voice: Have already eaten, have already eaten. :)

Comment: Well, this "myth" has been perpetuated, as it were, in the American edition of the famous Murphy's Grammar in Use. It says that in AmE it's possible to use Simple Past with the words "just", "already", "yet".

Comment: @Rusletov That is just silly. Since the Brits do it also. He's a Brit and should know better. It's really a numbers game. There are so many more Americans than Brits, he "figures" that.

Comment: I'll need to sleep on your explanation. Hope to get what you mean by "wants to signal without being specific" and "be specific", and I'll re-read your answers carefully more times.

Comment: Can I say, that I should use the perfect tenses in response if I try to justify myself?
Q:"Where have you been?" A: "I've been doing my homework with a classmate. Don't get angry!"

Q: "Where have you been?" A: "I was at the mall. But it's none of your business!"

Comment: @Rusletov In your PP, doing homework is the most important aspect of the sentence. NOT WHEN you did it. In your at the mall, it's the fact you were there and no longer are.